# Flutter: i can run my app but i cannot release APK

Tags: flutter

how can I release my App ? when I click on build APK I got this error

The Error is : Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

but I can run my app on debugging after i added "--no-sound-null-safety" in configuration >> Additional run args

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: how can i build APK or release my APP in Flutter with sound null safety error ?
right now i can just run my app and cannot release the app

Comment: @ArVaN903 Hey man, what dependencies don't support null safety? What does it say AFTER the part of the error you showed us?

Comment: - package:modal_progress_hud @Percent.twof

Comment: @ArVaN903 then that dependency (that you've put in the pubspec.yaml) is not null safety and therefore mostly useless lol. Try remove, replace or update it :)

Comment: @Percent.twof could you please tell me a new one name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a few dependencies that you've defined inside your PubSpec.yaml file do NOT support null safety while your project is using the new null safety configuration.

Either remove those dependencies (replace them with the ones that have a sound built in null safety) OR do this to turn OFF null safety in your flutter project :

Set SDK constraints in your project's pubspec.yaml file.

For example, the following, does not have null safety enabled:

> environment:   sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"

You can also specify at the top of your Dart file to disable null checks for that file.

> // @dart=2.9

Once done, build the apk again and it should work this time.

Comment: i have change that package with new one and it is fixed now ,Thanks buddy

Comment: Glad to hear that ! You're welcome.